# javascript-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

With this javascript:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{           $("a").each(function()
{             var i = $(this).attr("href");           
 var n = i.replace(http://www.yourdomain.com, "https://www.yourdomain.com");                               $(this).attr("href", function() {               return n             })           })         });       </script>
```

---

and this

```
(index):1394 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[_0x87da[1]] is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1394)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
(anonymous) @ (index):1394
c @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
ready @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
q @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
```

with this jquery

```
<b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
      <span id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl.https' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'><data:newerPageTitle/></a>
      </span>
    </b:if>
```

Please help me Fix This problem XD

Comment: `i.replace(http://www.yourdomain.com, "https://www.yourdomain.com")` should be `i.replace("http://www.yourdomain.com", "https://www.yourdomain.com")`

Comment: The replace could be shortened to `i.replace("http://", "https://")` unless you need the full domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that you are not using `"` in the first argument of `i.replace` and you have `//` after http so it take everything after `//` in that line as comment which make it something like this `i.replace(http//everything commented out including closing bracket` so the function never gets closed that's why gave `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error adding `"` them will solve your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").each(function() {
          var i = $(this).attr("href");
          var n = i.replace("http: //www.yourdomain.com", "https://www.yourdomain.com"); 
            $(this).attr("href", function() {
              return n
            })
          })
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you brother Its work now .. my Allah bless you

Comment: @DzTansan Glad, I helped please accept and upvote the answer so that if anyone faces the same issue in future they can get it correct

Comment: i cant vote im new here this first question went i get 15 reputation ill vote up .. add Fav page .

Comment: Done i have other probelm Can you help me

Comment: I have the same name as the error but not Java                                          <b:includable id='mobile-index-post' var='post'>
  <div class='mobile-date-outer date-outer'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
      <div class='date-header'>
        <span><data:post.dateHeader/></span>
      </div>
    </b:if>

Comment: if you want i will modifie my question and add this question

Comment: put it as a separate question and include that language tag also :)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `replace` needs to be either a string or a regular expression: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: i dont understand This Code ... Can you Fix it ?

Comment: @DzTansan check my answer